# having issues scrolling to the end of NSScrollView programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nsscrollview

i have a `NSScrollView` that every time i click a button , an object adds up in the scrollview , i added the code below , so each time i press the button and the object adds in the scrollview , my scrollview scrolls to the end of scroll view where the new object is added :

```
let widthcc = scollingView.documentView!.frame.size.width + 156
    scollingView.contentView.scrollPoint( NSPoint ( x: widthcc, y: 0))
```

but  i am not getting the result i want , whatever i do the new scrolling position in one object behind my actual last added object.

what am i doing wrong?

heres my xcode project :
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/64067896/2_infinite_scrolle.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fast solution is this:

```
     @IBAction func myButtonAction(sender: AnyObject) {
    add()

    NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {[unowned self] in

        let widthcc = self.scollingView.documentView!.frame.size.width + 156
        print(widthcc)
        self.scollingView.contentView.scrollPoint( NSPoint ( x: widthcc, y: 0))
    }

}
```

It lets layout completing resizing you view and then scroll to the end in the cycle of UI loop.

Comment: thank you very much Eugene that worked perfectly.
but i'm a little confused , i thought that the code runs line by line , so the add() function should run first and the layout should resize prior to the scrollPoint method! can you tell me why is that ?

Comment: Layout process has several stages where several flags are used. It is pretty complex process. In reality the logic for adding items should actually be different. There is whole bunch of WWDC videos of how layout works so you can learn a bit from them. That's why I said it is "fast" solution. I cannot provide better code snippet because I need to remember learn those sequences and flags as well (i used that long ago and forgot already).